# Объясните пожалуйста почему выдает ошибку TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, палиндромы

Пытаюсь решить задачу на проверку числа на палиндром. Преобразовал число в список(как я думаю), затем пытаюсь проверить каждый символ и получаю каждый раз ошибку.

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        res = list(map(int, str(x)))
        for i in len(res):
            tmp = res[:i] + res[i+1:]
            if tmp == tmp[::-1]:
                True
            else:
                False
```

Comment: `for i in len(res):` -> `for i in range(len(res)):`

Comment: Ошибка: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: Да у вас в целом код какой-то дикий, тут всё нужно переделывать. Ну. видимо, в качестве `x` приходит не число теперь. Типизация в Питоне не обязательная, так что гарантии, что вызовут функцию именно с числом нет. Так то цикл вообще не нужен, вы можете сразу вернуть `return res == res[::-1]`. Да и в `int` не нужно преобразовывать, достаточно `res = list(str(x))`